# Trouble converting IDs to name values in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with the following values:

```
----+-----------------+-----------------+
id  | player1_char_id | player2_char_id |
----+-----------------+-----------------+
1   | 8               | 88              |
----+-----------------+-----------------+
```

`player1_char_id` and `player2_charid` both reference IDs from another `character` table. I'm trying to join the two tables and display the characters' names instead, with the following desired result:

```
----+--------------+--------------+
id  | player1_char | player2_char |
----+--------------+--------------+
1   | Yoshimitsu   | Fahkumram    |
----+--------------+--------------+
```

However, I get no results whatsoever when I try and query the data to achieve the above result with the following code:

```sql
SELECT match.id, character.first_name AS player1_char, character.first_name AS player2_char
FROM match
JOIN character
  ON match.player1_char_id = character.id AND match.player2_char_id = character.id;
```

When I change the `AND` to `OR` in the `JOIN` statement, I get duplicate values in both name columns, i.e.

```
----+--------------+--------------+
id  | player1_char | player2_char |
----+--------------+--------------+
1   | Yoshimitsu   | Yoshimitsu   |
----+--------------+--------------+
```

How can I fix my query to achieve the aforementioned desired result?

Comment: You need to do 2 joins.

Comment: @Zakaria Kindly explain further

Comment: A single column in a single row isn't going to have two different values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT match.id, 
       character_a.first_name AS player1_char,
       character_b.first_name AS player2_char
FROM match
JOIN character as character_a
  ON match.player1_char_id = character_a.id
JOIN character as character_b
  ON match.player2_char_id = character_b.id;
```

Comment: That worked; I didn't realise you could provide aliases for tables in a JOIN statement. Thanks!

Comment: Accept the answer?

Comment: I will soon ... I can't accept it for 6 more minutes apparently